# Background Process as NSOperation or Thread to monitor and update File

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift4

I want to check if a pdf file is changed or not, and if is changed i want to update the corresponding view. I don't know if it's more suitable to use a background process as a Thread or as an NSOperation to do this task. The Apple Documentation says: "Examples of tasks that lend themselves well to NSOperation include network requests, image resizing, text processing, or any other repeatable, structured, long-running task that produces associated state or data.But simply wrapping computation into an object doesn’t do much without a little oversight".

Also, if I understood correctly from the documentation, a Thread once started can't be stopped during his execution while an NSOperation could be paused or stopped and also they could rely on dependency to wait the completion of another task.

The workflow of this task should be more or less this diagram:

[Task workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akuz5.png)

Comment: I would use a private dispatch queue with `DispatchWorkItem` or `Operation`. But don't *check* (poll), create a `DispatchSourceFileSystemObject` with appropriate flags and handle the event notification about the changes.

Comment: It's the first time that i am implementing a background process in swift but the idea should be to monitor changes/corruption in a background process but update the pdf file (the UI) calling the dispatch main queue from the background process( Correct me if i am wrong ;) ). Also, are you suggesting a private queue ( also know as a serial queue) because my task is supposed to be executed in serial and not concurrently as with the global queue?.

Comment: With *private* I mean a separate, dedicated queue for the monitoring

Comment: But even a serial queue it's a private one, because it's not provided automatically from the API but you should create it manually. I am also reading that i can use a NSTimer in the main thread that call every some seconds a function that will handle the monitor and the update of the file all in the main queue. What do you think about this approach, obviously is more simple, but does i really need to use a background process to do this task even if it shouldn't overload the main queue?

Comment: For example to create a serial queue the documentation says to write this code:   "dispatch_queue_t queue; queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);”.  Otherwise i could use the 4 global queues provided by the system but those are also concurrently queue which i don't need to do this task, because i am supposed to do one task at time.

Comment: Forget the `Timer` solution. It might be simple but is really bad. Once again **do not poll**, never do that. Monitor the file with `DispatchSourceFileSystemObject` on an own queue and dispatch UI related code to the main queue. In Swift 4 you create a dispatch queue with `DispatchQueue(label:)`, don't use the C-API

Comment: What do you mean by 'don't poll' ? you mean i should not write manually the code needed to check if the file was changed (through his Date) but instead i should use the API provided like using the Dispatch sources as you were suggesting?

Comment: Yes, *don't ask, tell*. Use an API which notifies about changes. It's much more efficient than polling (run code periodically to check something)

Comment: I can't find in DispatchSource.FileSystemEvent the event to handle the change to a file, are you sure the DispatchSourceFileSystemObject is the correct way instead of using the NSFilePresenter of the File System?

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure. I'm using this API in a couple of projects. Are *you* sure to read the *Swift 4* documentation?

Comment: In DispatchSource.FileSystemEvent as type properties i read: all, attrib, delete, extend, funlock, link, rename, revoke, write. Where is the change event? I am reading following the official API: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsource.filesystemevent .

Comment: If i understand correctly the changes to the file should come from the write event in  DispatchSource.FileSystemEvent.

Comment: I will try to implement it and will post a solution or will ask for help if needed because if you are already using it in two projects you are certainly more experienced about this kind of things than me; from what i am reading your suggestion rely on directly using GCD layer which is,if a remember correctly from the documentation, a deeper layer and thus more difficult to use than NSOperation which is more abstract.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the handler working after the notification of type .write has been sent. If i monitor for example a *.txt file everything works as expected and i receive only one notification. But i am monitoring a pdf file which is generated from terminal by pdflatex and thus i receive with '.write' nearly 15 notification. If i change to '.attrib' i get 3 notification. I need the handler to be called only once, not 15 or 3 times. Do you have any idea how can i do it or is not possible with a Dispatch Source? Maybe there is a way to execute a dispatchWorkItem only once?

Comment: Just cancel the handler after receiving the first notification.

Comment: @vadian i have tried that but then when should i reassign the handler? because if the file has changed and i do all my stuff ( call the main thread from my serial queue to update the view) i will no longer receive future event notification, thus i should restart the startMonitoring() function but that doesn't seem to me a good solution. I have add an answer to explain better what i need to do.

Comment: I would `suspend` and `resume` the source and add a logic to skip consecutive events of the same kind.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement it like this(This is inside a FileMonitor class):

```
func startMonitoring()
{

    ....
      let fileSystemRepresentation = fileManager.fileSystemRepresentation(withPath: fileStringURL)

      let fileDescriptor = open(fileSystemRepresentation, O_EVTONLY)

      let newfileMonitorSource = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(fileDescriptor: fileDescriptor,
                                                             eventMask: .attrib,
                                                             queue: queue)

      newfileMonitorSource.setEventHandler(handler: 
      {
        self.queue.async 
        {  
          print(" \n received first write event, removing handler..." )

          self.newfileMonitorSource.setEventHandler(handler: nil)

          self.test()
        }
      })

      self.fileMonitorSource = newfileMonitorSource
      fileMonitorSource!.resume()
  }


func test()
  {
    fileMonitorSource?.cancel()
    print(" restart monitoring ")
    startMonitoring()
  }
```

I have tried to reassign the handler in test(), but it's not working(if a regenerate the pdf file, what is inside the new handler it's not executed) and to me, doing in this way, it seems a bit boilerplate code. I have also tried the following things:

- suspend the DispatchSource in the setEventHandler of startMonitoring() (passing nil), but then when i am resuming it, i get the remaining .write events.
- cancel the DispatchSource object and recall the startMonitoring() as you can see in the code above,  but in this way i create and destroy the DispatchSource object everytime i receive an event, which i don't like because the cancel() function shoul be called in my case only when the user decide to disable this feauture i am implementing.

I will try to write better how the workflow of the app should be so you can have an more clear idea of what i am doing:

- When the app starts, a functions sets the default value of some checkboxes of the window preference. The user can modify this checkboxes. So when the user open a pdf file, the idea is to launch in a background thread the following task:

  - I create a new queue call it A and launch asynch an infinite while where i check the value of the UserDefault checkboxe (that i use to reload and update the pdf file) and two things could happen

    - if the user set the value to off and the pdf document has been loaded there could be two situations:

      - if there is no current monitoring of the file (when the app starts): continue to check the checkboxe value
      - if there is currently a monitoring of the file: stop it
    - if the user set value to on and the pdf document has been loaded in this background thread (the same queue A) i will create a class Monitor (that could be a subclass of NSThread or a class that uses DispatchSourceFileSystemObject like above), then i will call startMonitoring() that will check the date or .write events and when there is a change it will call the handler. Basically this handler should recall the main thread (the main queue) and check if the file can be loaded or is corrupted and if so update the view.

**Note**: The infinite while loop(that should be running in the background), that check the UserDefault related to the feature i am implementing it's launched when the user open the pdf file.

Because of the problem above (multiple handlers calls), i should use the cancel() function when the user set checkboxe to off, and not create/destroy the DispatchSource object everytime i receive a .write event.

Comment: Once again, you are strongly discouraged from any kind of **polling** (the infinite while loop) unless you have absolutely no choice. Here you got a choice. Use KVO (key-value observing) to get notified when the value of the checkbox changes.

Comment: @vadian Yes KVO is in my list of things to learn,but at the moment as a student i have a deadline and i have currently implementing this thing using the UserDefault class. You said:

'I would suspend and resume the source and add a logic to skip consecutive events of the same kind.'

So the idea is to skip the same type of event (for example the '.write' event) in the body of the handler. How i could detect the type of event that is coming ? should i use the FirstResponder, or maybe the queue i created ? Could you provide an example?

Comment: The `DispatchSource` object has a `data` property which returns the current event flag(s).

Comment: I have managed to launch the handler only once. Do you know if it's possible (using the queue or as i did with another feature using NSApplication.shared.nextEvent() ) to launch the handler only when the last event is sent? because i could use sleep() or some sort of other delay to wait until all writing of a row has been sent before doing the task in the handler but seems not a good solution.  


Also in your opinion is it normal that my app consume when it starts 114 mb and then it nearly doubles to 277 MB after i launch my serial queue/background thread ?

Comment: @vadian Also, when i should do some task in the main thread (from my serial queue), is it a good approach to use the Observable/Observer pattern so i can notify a ViewController of some changes and thus i can use a function declared in that controller or is better to pass the controller to the FileMonitor and use the controller in the main.async block?

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
          
            //code here
        }